# Ruby on Rails - devise error with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, devise

Everything was fine when I use `localhost:3000`, and I can visit `localhost:3000/users/sign_in`.

However, after I push to `heroku`, I can't visit this page and other pages which were created by `devise` and show this

[image]

Here is my `Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'  
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'    
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production    
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'   
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0' 
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'  
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'devise'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'rails_bootstrap_navbar'
```

Here is `heroku log`

```
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081619+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:822:in `exec_no_cache'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081621+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in `exec_query'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081622+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:976:in `column_definitions'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081623+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:187:in `columns'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081625+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:93:in `block in prepare_default_proc'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081626+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:44:in `yield'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081627+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:44:in `columns'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081629+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:214:in `columns'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081630+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:223:in `columns_hash'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081632+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:180:in `subclass_from_attributes?'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081633+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:23:in `new'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081634+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise/models/registerable.rb:20:in `new_with_session'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081640+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081642+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081643+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081641+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081638+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081649+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081636+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.5.1/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:100:in `build_resource'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081656+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081637+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.5.1/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:7:in `new'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081648+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081644+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081645+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081659+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081647+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081655+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081657+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081662+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081661+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081665+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081663+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081658+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081669+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081671+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081668+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081667+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081672+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081676+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081673+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081674+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081677+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081681+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081678+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081680+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081682+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081684+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.8/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081686+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081685+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081687+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081689+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081690+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081691+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081692+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081693+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081696+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081695+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081697+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081698+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081700+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081701+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081702+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081707+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081709+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081710+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081711+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081712+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081714+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081715+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081716+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081717+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081728+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081729+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081730+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081731+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081733+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081734+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081735+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081736+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081738+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081739+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081740+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081743+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081742+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081744+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081746+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081747+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081748+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081750+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081751+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081752+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081754+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081755+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081756+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081758+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081759+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081763+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081760+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2015-07-16T16:35:48.081762+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-16T16:35:51.501741+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=intelligent-madame-5204.herokuapp.com request_id=46eca4a7-c0ce-4dbf-bfb1-651fb7ae201b fwd="180.218.172.11" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=133
```

**Solution**

---

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: did you run : heroku run rake db:migrate ?

Comment: ahh, this is solution haha. I had run this command before, but I forgot to run again after adding `devise`.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to migrate your database.

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate --app your_app
```

This is a common step to forget when when deploying to Heroku.